# Smartgit installation on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: git, ubuntu-16.04, smartgit

I have installed smartgit on ubuntu using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eugenesan/ppa 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install smartgithg
```

but whenever I run the smartgit I get the message download the new version. I downloaded the package from the official site but it does-not seem to be containing the executable script.How to fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try instead to download the Debian package deb from the [Smargithg download page](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/download) instead.

Double-click on it, or try a [command-line installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line).
Presumably, that would install the [17.1.1 latest version](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/changelog.txt).